# What's the purpose of stirring the mixture at 0 degree and dding NaOH to the organic reaction mixture?

Tags: synthesis

I used to follow the lab protocol without thinking, but I now hope to understand why certain procedures are done.
I am synthesizing dimethoxyacetic acid from methyl dimethoxy acetate(so hydrolysis from ester to COOH).

1. Add lithium hydroxide monohydrate (89.5 mmol, 3.75 g,1.2 equiv) to a solution of methyl dimethoxyacetate (74.6 mmol, 10 g, 1 equiv) in dioxane (45 mL) and water (45 mL) at 0 °C.
2. Stir the mixture for 1 h at 0 °C and one additional hour at room temperature.
3. Add sodium hydroxide (1M aq soln, 75 mL) to the mixture.
4. Extract the mixture with diethyl ether (375 mL).
5. Acidify the recovered aqueous layer with hydrogen chloride (6N aq soln) until a pH of 1-2.
6. Extract the organics with diethyl ether (375 mL).
7. Dry the combined organic layers with magnesium sulfate and filter.
8. Evaporate the solvent slowly under reduced pressure to obtain 2,2-dimethoxyacetic acid.

I thought the reason why you acidify the aq. layer was to convert -COONa or -COOLi (ester salts) in the layer to acid (-COOH). Then doesn't it mean that the product I want ( dimethoxyacetic acid ) will be in the aqueous layer? Why do I need to care about the organic layer?

Would appreciate any insight&help!

Comment: For 6 - don't you mean extract the aq phase with ether? Also 7 seems to suggest that you combine the ether phase from 4 with the ether phase from 6.

Comment: Your description does not make sense at all! You say first that you are making the acid, then in 8, you say you get the "acid chloride" ?

Comment: @SteffX yeah you are right, amended step 8. it was a mere typo

Comment: @Waylander so after extraction with diethyl ether, I thought the organic layer would be consisted of : (1) some unreacted ester (starting material) & (2) diethyl ether, and the aq. layer would be of (1)sodium acetate (2) dioxane (3) water obviously & (4) dioxane and possibly LiOMe. What I don't get is the next instruction... they say I need to dry the **organic** layer to retrieve the product, but isn't it the aq. layer where my desired acid will be located?

Comment: Instruction 6 is misleading. Once the aq layer is acidified in 5 your product will extract into ether. I would extract the acidified aq phase with ether at least 3 times to make sure you get all the product. You then combine these ether extractions and dry them.

Comment: @Waylander you are amazing, thank you